# Show each letter from sentence which equal with vowel

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to make a program that shows each letter of a sentence which is equal with vowel. In below example with `for_loop();` function shows how it should look. My problem is that when i want to make this task with `while_loop();` function, the program work weird. And i don't understand why ?

```js
function for_loop(sentence) {
  var vowel = "aeouiAEOUI";
  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vowel.length; j++) {
      if (sentence[i] === vowel[j]) {
        console.log(sentence[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

for_loop("well");

function while_loop(sentence) {
  var vowel = ["a", "e", "o", "u", "i", "A", "E", "O", "U", "I"];
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

  while (i < sentence.length) {
    i++;
    while (j < vowel.length) {
      // console.log("i=" + i + " j=" +j);
      if (sentence[i] === vowel[j]) {
        console.log(sentence[i]);
      }

      j++;
    }
  }
}

while_loop("the program work weird");
```

Comment: Your not setting `j` to 0 on `i` itteration, like you do in the for loop version..  eg.  `i++; j = 0;`

Comment: _the program work weird_ isn't a very useful problem description. What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Please google how to debug javascript. Add a `degbugger;` and go line by line and check the value of `i` and `j` in every iteration, you'll see the issue the Keith mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. The problem is you were starting at position 1 of i, also, see that after first J's while ends, J is not set to 0 again, so the program will be comparing with the last vowel always.

```
function while_loop(sentence) {
  var vowel = ["a", "e", "o", "u", "i", "A", "E", "O", "U", "I"];
  var i = 0;

  while (i < sentence.length) {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < vowel.length) {
      // console.log("i=" + i + " j=" +j);
      if (sentence[i] === vowel[j]) {
        console.log(sentence[i]);
      }

      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: A comment of the change or what was wrong would be appreciated.